# Problemas para escrever uuid convertido de binary(16) em arquivo csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, uuid

A partir de uma query no `MySQL` recebo linhas com o campo no formato `binary(16)` do `MySQL`.
Faço a conversão usando a lib `uuid` e tento inserir em um arquivo `csv`.

Não escreve no formato `uuid` no arquivo `csv`, mas nos formatos:

- `b'\x00\x03+\x9b.\xd25L\xac\xc2\x1a\xbe\x1b Xy',15`
- `b"b'\\x00\\x03+\\x9b.\\xd25L\\xac\\xc2\\x1a\\xbe\\x1b Xy'"`

**Código:**

```
with open('consumer_req.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    headerFields = ['Consumer_id', 'Frequência']

    writer.writerow(headerFields)

    for row in results:
        bytearray_id, count = row

        byte_id = bytes(bytearray_id)

        print("\n", byte_id, " Type: ", type(byte_id))
        #Printa - b'\x00\x03+\x9b.\xd25L\xac\xc2\x1a\xbe\x1b Xy'  Type:  <class 'bytes'>

        consumer_id = uuid.UUID(bytes=byte_id)

        id_str = str(byte_id)

        print(id_str)
        #Printa - 00032b9b-2ed2-354c-acc2-1abe1b205879 -> O que eu quero no csv

        writer.writerow([id_str, str(count)])
```

**Como vem o csv:**

```
Consumer_id,Frequência
b'\x00\x03+\x9b.\xd25L\xac\xc2\x1a\xbe\x1b Xy',15
b'\x00\x03\xe5\xb9\x9f\xf3>]\x83\x86\xdex\xec\xf9\xf1=',6
b'\x00\x05\x8f\xa2\x9b|7\xa7\x8b\xf5J\xb8\xd9~\xf1\xcd',11
b'\x00\rx\xd6\xec\t?9\x86\xee\xfen2k\x9d\x04',7
"b""\x00't\x80\xeef5\xd8\x95\x10\x1d\x87~\xa6+b""",7
"b'\x00/\xca\xe1 G>\x9d\x96n1\xcd\xaf,<\xb1'",11
"b'\x003\xce\x1b\xe9\x017\xc7\x8a\xc3|g\x0f\xcf""\x9d'",7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível utilizar o package `uuid` para transformar bytes em string, ou uma representação de um UUID. Segue a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html).

Veja o exemplo:

```
import uuid
a = b'\x00\x03+\x9b.\xd25L\xac\xc2\x1a\xbe\x1b Xy' #utilizando o byte que forneceu na pergunta
c = uuid.UUID(bytes=a)
print(c)
#UUID('00032b9b-2ed2-354c-acc2-1abe1b205879')
# para imprimir a string basta fazer o cast para str.
str(c)
#'00032b9b-2ed2-354c-acc2-1abe1b205879'
```

Para fazer a conversão eu utilizei o construtor que aceita bytes como parâmetro, assim eu consigo exibir os dados na representação adequada.